# Try catch instead of multiple if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

I'm currently working on a student's project in Java (Android to be specific). Let's say I have a function that is called when a button is clicked. This method has to call few other short private functions (that return true/false) in order to check whetver e.g: user entered valid name, folder creation went ok, files were succesfully copied etc. Those things has to be checked before moving to another activity.

1. way to do this is by calling multiple 'ifs' with 'return' if sth went wrong:

   ```
   public void onClickButton(View view) {

       if( validData() ) {
           showErrorMsg("Wrong input!");
           return;
       }

       if( selectedFileExists() ) {
           showErrorMsg("File does not exist!");
           return;
       }

       if( createFolder() ) {
           showErrorMsg("Error during folder creation!");
           return;
       }

       (...)
   }
   ```
2. It's not bad, but I was thinking about replacing those short boolean functions with void methods that throw an exception which is catched in onClickButton(), eg:

   ```
   public void onClickButton(View view) {

       try {
           validData();
           selectedFileExists();
           createFolder();
           (...)           
       } 
       catch (MyException e) {
           showErrorMsg(e);
           return;
       }
   }


   private void createFolder() throws MyException {
       if( !projectFolder.mkdir() )
              throw new MyException("Error during folder creation!");
   }
   ```

**So what do you think about that second approach? Is it acceptable to use exceptions in that context?**

Comment: In general, `Exception`(s) should be used for exceptional circumstances. Your testing against primitives would be much faster.

Comment: Yes this is what exceptions are designed for this is exactly how you should use and exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let it be said that the first bit is inconsistent and your methods have bad names (methods are verbs, so to speak, and your methods aren't terribly descriptive of what they might be doing). Additionally, I'd expect your methods to return `false` on a failure, not `true`. I'd imagine better names being `isValidData`, `doesSelectedFileExist`, and `tryCreateFolder`. I'd also switch the logic around so the boolean return value is consistent with the method name.

That being said, let's get to the 2nd code segment. Exceptions are for exceptional behavior. I think your methods are *expected* to either return true or false, not an exception. Plus, exception handling should be allowed to bubble up to a more high-level exception handler.

Stick with the first segment with the changes I've outlined.

Comment: Thanks, those were just imaginary functions, in my code they have different names ;)

I've read few aricles about using exceptions and I'm leaning toward a statement, that they are not suitable for my purpose. So I guess I'm gonna stick with 'ifs'... but damn... this try-catch looks really neat! :D

Comment: @rafakob I would absolutely throw exceptions on *exceptional* behavior and add more info/context to the exception, but I would not throw in order to control the flow of logic. Here's a good programmers.stackoverflow.com discussion on the topic: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Answer (score 0):

You can create it by Second method as long as code is consise and easy to read.
Some of the tips that i can give you

1. Create Seperate class for validation(this class should extend the Exception class)
2. Create all validation method like date, telephone number,etc in a separate function. This way you can improve readability of the code and keep it modular.